# Find the minimum value of $\frac{4}{4-x^2} + \frac{9}{9-y^2} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $x, y ∈ (−2, 2)$ and $xy = −1$. Find the minimum value of $\frac{4}{4-x^2} + \frac{9}{9-y^2} $ ?
My Attempt
let $t=\frac{4}{4-x^2} + \frac{9}{9-y^2} $ , replacing $y$ by $- \frac{1}{x}$ we get $t=\frac{1}{1-(\frac{x}{2})^2} + \frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{3x})^2} $ . Using AM-HM inequality we get $t(1-(\frac{x}{2})^2 + 1-(\frac{1}{3x})^2) \geq 2^{2}.$  let $ m =(1-(\frac{x}{2})^2 + 1-(\frac{1}{3x})^2)$ and using AM-GM inequality we get $m \leq 5/3$.
But from this point my inequality signs are getting mixed up. Am I on right track?

Comment: tried deriving it and finding minumum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using AM-GM repeatedly:
$$\frac4{4-x^2}+\frac9{9-y^2} \ge \frac2{\sqrt{(1-x^2/4)(1-y^2/9)}} \ge \frac4{2-(x^2/4+y^2/9)}$$

Further, again as $\dfrac{x^2}4+\dfrac{y^2}9 \ge \dfrac13|xy|=\dfrac13$, we have
$$\frac4{4-x^2}+\frac9{9-y^2} \ge \frac4{2-\frac13}=\frac{12}5$$

Equality and the constraint is satisfied when $x = \sqrt{\frac23}, y = -\sqrt{\frac32}$, so that is the minimum.

Comment: CS could be used as well, in the same manner, as long as you keep an eye on maintaining the equality conditions and sign constraints.

Comment: thanks. Nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : The previous solution was utterly mistaken.

Let$$\frac{4}{4-x^2} + \frac{9}{9-y^2} =f(x,y)$$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{36}{36-9x^2}+\frac{36}{36-4y^2} \ge \frac{(6+6)^2}{72-9x^2-4y^2} (\because \text{Cauchy})\ge \frac{144}{60}=\frac{12}{5}(\because \text {AM-GM})$$

Comment: this also causing problem. If i take $x^{2} +y^{2}-2=u$ the it become $\frac{u}{u-11}$. Any attempt to use Am -GM is leading $\sqrt{xy}$ and $xy=-1$

Comment: @rugi the main problem is that this find the maxima of $f(x,y)$ (which does not even exist) not the minima.

Comment: @rugi The answer is (B), with near certainty. I am still working on proving it.

Comment: Now it is making sense. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f(x,y) = f(x) = \dfrac{4}{4-x^2} +\dfrac{9x^2}{9x^2-1}$. Let $u = x^2$, then $0 \leq u < 4$, and you get a relatively nice rational function in $u$ that you can use derivative to solve.

Comment: I think the reason the user didn't do this is because this is contest math-and I suspect he (or she) is talking about Olympiad Math, where you can't use derivatives.

Comment: @MXYMXY I have tried with derivative as suggested by Kf-Sansoo but it is not leading me anywhere.

Comment: @rugi You sure about the problem? There does not seem to be a minimum here. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minima+of+4%2F%7B4-x%5E2%7D+%2B%7B9x%5E2%7D%2F%7B9x%5E2-1%7D. No global minima found. Even with the constraint that $x, y ∈ (−2, 2)$

Comment: please see page 5 problem 18  http://www.isical.ac.in/~deanweb/dean_bstat_bmath_2012.pdf

Comment: @rugi note, $ \dfrac{1}{4} \le u<4 $, not $u >0$, because when $ u < \dfrac{1}{4} \implies y>2$ ,now you can find min.

Answer (score 0):

here is another elementary method which can also find min.

$f=\dfrac{4}{4-u}+\dfrac{9u}{9u-1},u=x^2=\dfrac{1}{y^2}< 4, y^2 < 4 \implies u> \dfrac{1}{4}$

$9(f-1)u^2+(72-37f)u+4(f-1)=0, \Delta=(72-37f)^2-4*4*9(f-1)^2 \ge 0 $

$\iff (12-5f)(12-7f)\ge 0 \iff f\ge \dfrac{12}{5}$ or $f \le \dfrac{12}{7}$

when $f \le \dfrac{12}{7}, 72-37f>0 \implies u<0$

when $f=\dfrac{12}{5}, u= \dfrac{37f-72}{2*9(f-1)}=\dfrac{2}{3} > \dfrac{1}{4}  \implies f_{min}=\dfrac{12}{5}$